# Why this JSP example doesn't work with maven and Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat

I have just started self-teaching web development with Java. I followed the instructions of a book teaching Web development with Java and used the JSP example provided by the book. However, when run, the JSP doesn't show the expected effects.

The source code for the JSP is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>First JSP</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <p>
                This is a simple HTML page that has a form in it.
            <p>
                The hobby was received as: <strong>${param.hobby}</strong>
            <p>
            Hobby: <input type='text' name='hobby' value=''>
            <input type='submit' name='confirmButton' value='Confirm'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could get the page "firstJSP.jsp" to show up in the Safari browser on my MacBook.

[image]

This may show that Maven and Tomcat are running. But when I entered a hobby in the text filed field after "Hobby:" on the webpage and pressed the "Confirm" button. The "${param.hobby}" text, which should have shown up there", didn't change into the hobby name I entered. This means that the JSP was treated as an ordinary HTML page.

The "firstJSP.jsp" file is in the directory shown below:

[image]

The book only gave the source code example and wasn't clear about where the example should be placed in the project directory and how it should be used.

Please let me know where the problem lies and how to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you deploy your application? You JSP page is apparently served as static resource.

Comment: Thank you, @PiotrP.Karwasz. I've got no idea what to do. I just followed the example in the book, but it didn't work. However, the example in the book works. In the book, a link is given and when I clicked the link, a jsp page was returned. That page worked. The link is "https://bytesizebook.com/guide-boot/ch1/OnePage/First.jsp".